# Get Java List<String> from javascript Http request

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json

I'm working with a Java backend with Spring MVC framework, I have a service that takes a List and remove some objects in a database. When I use Postman I send the next JSON object:

```
["ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
"73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
"50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
"c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc"]
```

Then I used a service in Angularjs sending this object:

```
$scope.accounts = new Array("ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
"73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
"50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
"c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc");
```

But I got this error:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

This problem does not occurs with other JSON objects, for example:

From Postman:

```
{
    "accountName":"XxxxxXXxxxx",
    "paymentMethodMain":"Medio Pago",
    "accountType":"xx",
    "accountNumber":"123456AA"
}
```

And from Angular:

```
 $scope.account = {
     "accountName":"XxxxxXXxxxx",
     "paymentMethodMain":"Medio Pago",
     "accountType":"xx",
     "accountNumber":"123456AA"
};
```

In this case all works correctly.

Comment: Do you get this message on the server or in the client? Perhaps you can show the entire request body being sent to the server. My initial guess is your payload is not a correct JSON payload.

Comment: @Jeroen I got these error in the client, and in the server a got this one: > Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.Object com.payulatam.ppp4.secure.api.controllers.AccountController.deleteAsobancariaAccount(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't post an array like this. Either you have to send the array as string/text in request body and parse in server side or do something like

```
$scope.accounts = new Array("ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
"73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
"50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
"c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc");
 // in your request send the array as value to a json key
{data: $scope.accounts }
```

in your server try

```
request.getParameterValues("data[]");
```